# android: preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

Is it possible to have two separate preferences in an app ?
I have an app that connects to an external executable (engine) at run time. The app has its own preferences, and the engine has that too. Those two can not mix because next time the user may decide to load a completely different engine with different preferences. So I want to load the preferences for the current engine , show it to the user as needed , and then exit without saving. I like the preference activity view that is displayed by default, and I was wondering if I can use that for the engine too.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many preferences as you want.  You just have to call them different things.

Comment: Thanks. Can I also delete preferences (like it never existed) when an app exits ? I don't want any preferences from the engine to be remembered on exit.

Comment: I have two preferences now. One is edited on the fly according to whatever options the external engine provides. My problem is how to display that one ? I have no XML file for that in the resource forlder so I can not use addPreferencesFromResource(). Can I construct a preference activity view just from sharedPreference variables ? Thanks